# Why rush Last Whisper in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've noticed a few people rushing Last Whisper as their first item. Particularly on characters like Talon, Zed and Kha'Zix, they go Brutalizer, Boots, Last Whisper.

Is scaling armour penetration really that useful so soon in the game? I understand getting flat armour pen early but surely more AD and/or crit will be better for assassinating squishy targets?

Comment: doesn't sound like a good build too. not when you're ahead and especially not when you're behind.

Comment: I suppose my previous question inspires you a bit (implicitly). Go see the answer of Jutschge. :)
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/200813/flat-ad-ap-over-penetration-ad-ap-during-the-laning-phase

Answer (score 6):

Last whisper becomes gold efficient against normal resistance targets (50 Armor) if you have around 180 AD. Now obviously the Percentage Armor Pen is exceptionally strong if you are playing against a Tanky, High-Armor Champion (or even Team).

Armor is usually easier to build than MR so people don't hesitate to buy it. Also a lot of AD Casters either play top or roam there pretty often which allows for more effective trades/ganks in terms of damage.

It's usually not recommended to buy LW early on when playing Talon vs Ahri if she isn't building any Armor and if you're not ganking but If there is a Nasus top who needs a shutdown for example you can rush LW and try to deny him as much as possible.

Lolwiki has a pretty nice Curve about the Gold Efficiency on LW.

[image]

Comment: This is a useful graph, but with that said, the champions he listed benefit greatly from early armor penetration due to high base ability damage.  If you want your spells to hit like trucks, armor pen is the way to go.  Obviously this varies with how the game is progressing, but thats generally a good thing to keep in mind.